# Batch script to parse output.txt and get new sql script based on lines from output.txt

Tags: sql, batch-file

THe following is output.txt file:

```
Changed database context to 'MY_DB'.
name                                                                                                                            
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
UserDomains                                                                                                                     
ApprovalConfiguration                                                                                                           
ApprovalLevelRoles                                                                                                              
CreditCardHolderTitle                                                                                                           
ApprovalRole                                                                                                                    

(22 rows affected)
name                                                                                                                            
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ApprovalConfigurationDelete                                                                                                     
ApprovalConfigurationInsert                                                                                                     
ApprovalConfigurationSelect                                                                                                     
ApprovalConfigurationsSelectAll                                                                                                 


(103 rows affected)
```

The following are names of SQL TABLES

```
UserDomains                                                                                                                     
ApprovalConfiguration                                                                                                           
ApprovalLevelRoles                                                                                                              
CreditCardHolderTitle                                                                                                           
ApprovalRole
```

... and this one are names of STORE PROCEDURES

```
ApprovalConfigurationDelete                                                                                                     
ApprovalConfigurationInsert                                                                                                     
ApprovalConfigurationSelect                                                                                                     
ApprovalConfigurationsSelectAll
```

I would like somehow to distinguish tables from store procedures.
Batch script should be able to produce one SQL file and populate it for each line of tables and store procedures from output.txt

So at the end new SQL file should be something like that:

```
-- TABLES
exec sp_addarticle @publication = N'$(PublicationName)', @article = N'UserDomains', @type = N'logbased'
GO
exec sp_addarticle @publication = N'$(PublicationName)', @article = N'ApprovalConfiguration', @type = N'logbased'
GO
exec sp_addarticle @publication = N'$(PublicationName)', @article = N'ApprovalLevelRoles', @type = N'logbased'
GO
exec sp_addarticle @publication = N'$(PublicationName)', @article = N'CreditCardHolderTitle', @type = N'logbased'
GO
exec sp_addarticle @publication = N'$(PublicationName)', @article = N'ApprovalRole', @type = N'logbased'
GO

-- STORE PROCEDURES
exec sp_addarticle @publication = N'$(PublicationName)', @article = N'ApprovalConfigurationDelete', @type = N'proc schema only'
GO
exec sp_addarticle @publication = N'$(PublicationName)', @article = N'ApprovalConfigurationInsert', @type = N'proc schema only'
GO
exec sp_addarticle @publication = N'$(PublicationName)', @article = N'ApprovalConfigurationSelect', @type = N'proc schema only'
GO
exec sp_addarticle @publication = N'$(PublicationName)', @article = N'ApprovalConfigurationsSelectAll', @type = N'proc schema only'
GO
```

Thanks guys for you help in advance!

The Sero

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Batch file below do the division you want, just complete output details.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /F %%a in (output.txt) do (
   set "line=%%a"
   if "!TABLE!" equ "true" (
      if "!line:~0,1!" neq "(" (
         echo TABLE: !line!
      ) else (
         set TABLE=false
      )
   ) else if "!PROC!" equ "true" (
      if "!line:~0,1!" neq "(" (
         echo PROC: !line!
      ) else (
         set PROC=false
      )
   ) else if not defined TABLE (
      if "!line:~0,1!" equ "-" (
         set TABLE=true
         echo -- TABLES
      )
   ) else if "!line:~0,1!" equ "-" (
      set PROC=true
      echo -- STORE PROCEDURES
   )
)
```